# How to convert VBS On error resume Next to java script

Tags: javascript, vbscript

```
On Error Resume Next
    frmDetail.Description<%=nLineCount%>.readonly = False
    frmDetail.DetailedDescription<%=nLineCount%>.readonly = False
On Error GoTo 0
```

I have above vb script code segment. I need to convert it in to java script. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 3):

```
// The direct translation:

try {
    frmDetail.Description<%=nLineCount%>.readonly = false;
} catch(err) {}

try {
    frmDetail.DetailedDescription<%=nLineCount%>.readonly = false;
} catch(err) {}



// The right way:

if (frmDetail)
{
    if (frmDetail.Description<%=nLineCount%>){
        frmDetail.Description<%=nLineCount%>.readonly = false;
    }
    if (frmDetail.DetailedDescription<%=nLineCount%>){
        frmDetail.DetailedDescription<%=nLineCount%>.readonly = false;
    }
}
```